# Referencing assemblies under dotnet installation directory

Tags: .net-core, .net-assembly, csproj

Wondering if there is any *legitimate* reason for a .csproj to contain an assembly reference to an assembly w/ a hint path under the `dotnet` installation directory (default: `c:\Program Files\dotnet` on Windows).

In particular, the directories

- packs
- sdk
- shared

An example of such a reference:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref\3.1.0\ref\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: No. Such is used by .NET Core SDK to locate framework assemblies, so not desired to be consumed by traditional project files.

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760356/how-do-i-use-asp-net-core-3-0-types-from-a-library-project-for-shared-controller if your goal is to use ASP.NET Core types from a library. You can also use NuGet packages for the Microsoft.Extensions stuff though.

Answer (score 0):

Surely not. This application would not work on other machines.

It looks like someone inserted code that uses Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions package which was not referenced and then probably applied "Quick fix" action from Resharper/Rider. Sometimes it leads not to referencing Nuget package

```
<ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="3.1.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

but to referencing locally placed assembly.

Comment: "This application would not work on other machines" - will the assembly not get copied to the build output directory still though? I'm not saying it's good/correct, I'm just saying the application _may_ still work once built.

Comment: Assembly surely will be copied to the output directory. I was talking about the scenario when a developer tries to build the application from source codes on the other machine.